# Problems when extracting a submatrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, submatrix

I am writing a piece of code to extract a submatrix from a matrix. As modules, I imported scipy and Image.  When I run the script, I got the error

```
submatrix = im[x_min:x_max, y_min:y_max]
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I checked and the min and max values are effectively integers... do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

```
x_min = int(x - 50)
x_max = int(x + 50)
y_min = int(y - 50)
y_max = int(y + 50)
if x_min < 0:
    x_min = 0
    continue
if y_min < 0:
    y_min = 0
    continue
if x_max > 2160:
    x_max = 2160
    continue
if y_max > 2592:
    y_max = 2592
    continue
submatrix = im[x_min:x_max, y_min:y_max]
figure(1)
imshow(submatrix)
break
```

Comment: I guess `im` is a numpy array?

Comment: Yes it's a matrix obtained by reading an image:                   image = Image.open("/...image_%03i.tif" % (index)); im = image.load()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `import Image` then your `im` object is not an numpy array but a PixelAccess object.
So if you really want a numpy array you could use `imread` instead of `Image.open`.

A minimal example (with `x_min` etc. being int) would be

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = plt.imread("/...image_%03i.tif" % (index))
submatrix = im[x_min:x_max, y_min:y_max]
plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(submatrix)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Jakob! Now I only need to find a way to plot my submatrix (now it doesn't pop out). Cheers!